# ReactJS and Spring Data Rest caching issue possibly related to websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, spring, reactjs, spring-data-rest

I seem to be having a weird caching problem.

I recently blew away my database.  After I started to create some new `users` within my system I noticed that a old user showed up.  This user has not been recreated and currently does not exist in the database.

I am not sure where to look for a caching issue, either from `Spring Data REST` or from `ReactJS`.  Does anyone know where this might be from?

I have `web sockets` setup as well.

Steps:

Blow away db:
Created a new user
Web socket does the creation
I then use `reactjs` to make a call to get a page of users from `Spring Data Rest`  this is where the weirdness happens.

Call to get the users

```
  Headers:

  Request URL:http://localhost:8081/api/users?size=4
  Request Method:GET
  Status Code:200 OK
  Remote Address:[::1]:8081

  Response Headers
  view source
  Content-Type:application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
  Date:Wed, 18 May 2016 22:25:29 GMT
  Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Transfer-Encoding:chunked

  Request Headers
  view source
  Accept:application/hal+json
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Type:text/plain
  Host:localhost:8081
  Referer:http://localhost:8081/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
  Query String Parameters
  view source
  view URL encoded
  size:4

  BODY:

  {
    "_embedded" : {
      "users" : [ {
        "firstName" : "Aaron",
        "lastName" : "Magi",
        "userName" : "amagi",
        "description" : "coding up a storm",
        "_links" : {
          "self" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8081/api/users/1"
          },
          "user" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8081/api/users/1"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "firstName" : "john",
        "lastName" : "smith",
        "userName" : "jsmith",
        "description" : "mr smith",
        "_links" : {
          "self" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8081/api/users/3"
          },
          "user" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8081/api/users/3"
          }
        }
      } ]
    },
    "_links" : {
      "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8081/api/users"
      },
      "profile" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8081/api/profile/users"
      }
    },
    "page" : {
      "size" : 4,
      "totalElements" : 2,
      "totalPages" : 1,
      "number" : 0
    }
  }
```

Internally I then make a call to the endpoint for the user details (http://localhost:8081/api/users/3).  **At this point it returns the old user details not the new details**

```
  Headers:

  Request URL:http://localhost:8081/api/users/3
  Request Method:GET
  Status Code:304 Not Modified
  Remote Address:[::1]:8081

  Response Headers
  view source
  Date:Wed, 18 May 2016 22:25:29 GMT
  ETag:"0"
  Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

  Request Headers
  view source
  Accept:application/hal+json
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Type:text/plain
  Host:localhost:8081
  If-None-Match:"0"
  Referer:http://localhost:8081/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36


  BODY

      {
        "firstName" : "Stephen",
        "lastName" : "Mann",
        "userName" : "smann",
        "description" : "Wizard",
        "_links" : {
          "self" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8081/api/users/3"
          },
          "user" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8081/api/users/3"
          }
        }
      }
```

webpack.config

```
  var path = require('path');

var node_dir = __dirname + '/node_modules';

module.exports = {
    entry: './app.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: false,
    debug: true,
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'stompjs': node_dir + '/stompjs/lib/stomp.js',
        }
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
                // TODO remove for production
                //loaders: ['react-hot','babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Application.properties

```
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Web server
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
server.port=8081

# TODO FOR DEBUG ONLY
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.freemarker.cache=false
spring.groovy.template.cache=false
spring.velocity.cache=false
spring.mustache.cache=false
server.session.persistent=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.resources.cache-period=0
```

**Question**

Where is the caching happening?  I can continue to create users and have them show up incorrectly with the old data.  Is there a way to correctly turn this off for your application?

I noticed while posting this question that I had cache:true in In my webpack.config.js.  But even setting this to false did not solve the issue.  After reading it sounds like this is to cache components not data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the caching was a IE related problem.  After further reading I determined I needed to setup the cache-control

```
'Pragma': 'no-cache', 

'Expires': '-1', 

'cache-control': 'no-cache'
```